# Ideal of the hyperbola in a field that is not algebraically closed.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $K$ a field not necessarily algebraically closed. I would like to find the coordinate ring of the hyperbola
$$
V(XY-1)\subseteq K^{2}.
$$
If the field was algebraically closed we could use Hilbert's Nullstellensatz to say that 
$$
I(V(XY-1))=\sqrt{(XY-1)}=(XY-1)\Rightarrow A(V(XY-1))=K[X,Y]/(XY-1)
$$
How could we prove that $I(V(XY-1))=XY-1$ (If this is the case) if $K$ is not algebraically closed?

It would also be easy if the curve was parametrizable, but the hyperbola is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course we need the field to be infinite. Here are two proofs:

1. Do it by hand: Let $f \in V(XY-1)$, i.e. $f(\frac{1}{x},x)=0$ for any $x \in K^*$.

We can do division with remainder w.r.t to $X$ and get $f=h(XY-1)+r$ with $r \in \frac{1}{Y}k[Y]$ and $h \in k(Y)[X].$ For any $x \in K^*$ we evaluate this equation at $(\frac{1}{x},x)$ and get $r(x)=0$, in particular $xr(x)=0$, hence $Yr \in k[Y]$ is the zero-polynomial, hence $r=0$. In particular this implies that $h(XY-1) \in k[Y][X]$. Looking at the coefficients of this polynomial it is easy to deduce that $h \in k[Y][X]$, from which we can conclude that $f \in (XY-1)$.

---

2. Use some algebra. We know $J := I(V(XY-1)) \supset (XY-1)$. Assume equality does not hold.

Note that $K[X,Y]/(XY-1)$ is a one-dimensional domain, i.e. $K[X,Y]/J$ is zero-dimensional if equality does not hold. Then $V(J)$ is finite, but $V(J)=V(XY-1)$ is infinite.